# Dotnet command failed with non-zero exit code on the following projects :

Tags: tfs, azure-devops

I am trying to build on TFS an API which contains several projects in dotnet.core3.1
When I run the dotnet build Api.sln command on TFS here is the result

### [error] Dotnet command failed with non-zero exit code on the following projects: D: \ TFS \ Agent01 \ _work \ 18 \ s \ PMTApi.sln

---

### Context:

TFS 2017

Dotnet Core 3.1 projects

Source code management on TFS git

Agents unable to connect to the outside (internet)

The dependency imports are done from a private server thanks to the NuGet.Config file set up to redirect the dependency imports not on the https://api.nuget.org/v3/index.json server but well on that of our private company.

---

### Explanation:

On the TFS git source manager, the PMTApi.sln project contains 7 .csproj files

But in the PMTApi.sln file there are only 4 .csproj which are included

---

### Local result:

Is good dotnet build completes the 5 successful projects.

---

### Result on TFS:

Not good.

### [error] Dotnet command failed with non-zero exit code on the following projects: D: \ TFS \ Agent01 \ _work \ 18 \ s \ PMTApi.sln

---

### Observation:

I have the impression that TFS is based on all the .csproj files from the TFS git source manager and not from PMTApi.sln
Conclusion the projects which are not referenced in PMTApi.sln still try to restore the dependencies which causes the top error.

---

### Test:

I tried to exclude these 3 .csproj projects in my NuGet.Config file like this, but it doesn't work

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <packageSources>
    <add key="XXX NuGet Packages" value="http://privateServer/nuget" />
  </packageSources>

    <ItemGroup>
        <ProjectReference Exclude="..\folderName1\projectName1.csproj" />
        <ProjectReference Exclude="..\folderName2\projectName2.csproj" />
        <ProjectReference Exclude="..\folderName3\projectName3.csproj" />
    </ItemGroup>
</configuration>
```

Do you have any ideas for a successful dotnet build task?

---

### The construction:

[image: definition pipeline CI]

---

### TFS Return:

[image: TFS return]

---

### Local configuration:

[image]

1- here you have to right click on the solution

2- manage package Nuget for solution

3- add the url of your private server

4- and uncheck the server of api.NuGet.org

for my case I also uncheck the visual studio packages

Comment: Can you show how you build it on tfs?

Answer (score 0):

You should specify the `csproj` file(s) to use in the `Project(s)` argument, not `sln` file. Check the description of this argument:

> The path to the csproj file(s) to use. You can use wildcards (e.g.
> **/*.csproj for all .csproj files in all subfolders). This field follows glob pattern, and is run against root of the repository at all
> times irrespective of Working Directory.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/dotnet-core-cli?view=azure-devops

Comment: By doing what you say.
I always have the same error:
Dotnet command failed with non-zero exit code on the following projects: on each of the projects.
In addition on each project an error telling me:
NETSDK1004: Assets file 'D: \ TFS \ Agent01 \ _work \ 18 \ s \ PMTApiWeb \ obj \ project.assets.json' not found. Run a NuGet package restore to generate this file. [D: \ TFS \ Agent01 \ _work \ 18 \ s \ PMTApiWeb \ PMTApiWeb.csproj]

Comment: I found as information that the restore NuGet, does not restore all the packages, for me I am missing the obj / project.json files

I then tried the command:
dotnet restore, if it works better except on one project.
Dotnet command failed with non-zero exit code on the following projects: D: \ TFS \ Agent01 \ _work \ 18 \ s \ PMTApicORE \ PMTApiCore.csproj
Here again I deduce that he cannot find a package on my private network.
It is difficult to find the subtle difference between the commands:
 NuGet restore and dotnet restore.

Comment: I think the problem comes from there, because without the restoration of dependencies, the projects will not be able to build correct.

Comment: You could go to build agent machine to check whether the packages the projects require are downloaded. Also, try to set variable system.debug to True and check the log to see whether there is more information.

Comment: How's your issue going?

Comment: I managed to configure my local working environment (VisualStudio 2019),
  the projects will directly consume the NuGet packages from the private server in my box, and no longer from the NuGet.org server.
  This is an important step to stop having to launch builds with CI pipelines. 

I will add a screenshot to explain the local configuration.
  From there I can verify that they are the build problem with visual studio 2019, and when it tells me that a NuGet package is missing I add it directly to the private server.

Comment: Now I am at a stage where there are packages that they do not want to install on the private server, and I do not understand why?

Comment: Go to the build agent machine, then clean the build directory and have another try.